# String: split / match Uppercase, space, specialchar

Tags: javascript, string, split, match, uppercase

I know that they are already a lot of question about the subject but no answer for this one
I've tried for a while to split:

```
var string = "ABC hereWeAre Againwith Those words";
```

to

```
['A','B','C','here','We','Are','Againwith','Those','words'];
```

(When there is a UpperCase or a Space).

I've tried with :

```
string.match(/[A-Z]+|[a-z]+|[0-9]+|[\S]+/g);
string.match(/[a-z]+/gi);
```

But nothing is working.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct regex for this would be:

```
"ABC hereWeAre Againwith Those words".match(/[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+/g);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly that !

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes (a bit complicated but still works):

```
"ABC hereWeAre Againwith Those words".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim().split(/\s+/);
// returns ["A", "B", "C", "here", "We", "Are", "Againwith", "Those", "words"]
```

Idea is to find uppercase letters, prepend those with space, then trim and split whole string by spaces. Note passing regular expression into `.split` to get rid of problem with more than one space one after another.